Issue regarding the concept of nextInLine in Javascript
I have recently started learning Javascript, and came across the concept of nextInLine function. Upon reading about it I found out that it is a defined function which basically takes a queue and an item as arguments and returns the deleted element from the queue.
But my question is can't any other function with a different name be used for the same purpose, and if yes why is nextInLine said to be a defined function in javascript?

nextInLine is not among the native functions of JavaScript. Maybe you refer to some platform that has defined this function for you to use, or one that you have to write yourself, like on freecodecamp.org.

^^ And yes, the function could have any name. They're just telling you what to call it for the assignment.

I've never heard of this function before and I've never tried to accomplish something like this before either. But it sounds like the function you want to create is to add something in a queue and remove one. The removed item gets returned.
function enqueueAndDequeue(queue, newItem) {
  queue.push(newItem);
  return queue.shift();
}

